# Reading 7 segment digits of weighing controller

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to read the 7-segment display of a industrial weighing machine. as there is no serial out port for the machine i have to note down the weight manually. the idea is to use python-computer vision to capture the weight and store it in text file. the image is as shown [image: 7 segment from weighing machine]. 
i have used the following [python](https://github.com/shanlau/SVM_Recognizing_Digit/blob/master/read_digit.py) code for this purpose.
the code runs fine till i am converting the image to gray. the converted image is [image: grayed image] . the problem starts when i start applying the threshold to the image. after applying the threshold the image is as shown [image: threshold image]any suggestions so as to how i should proceed.

Comment: Don't post links to code.  Post minimal code to reproduce the issue in the question itself as *text* so the question stands on its own.

Comment: Read the documentation of the threshold function, then ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, using just OpenCV and Pytesseract, seems to work okay:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("Cf8ko.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thres = img.max() * 0.9  # 90% of the maximum brightness
img[img < thres] = 0  # set all pixels below threshold to black
img[img >= thres] = 255  # set all pixels above threshold to white
img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)  # invert to black text on white background
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng")
print(text)
```

This prints out

```
9830
```

and the processed image looks like

[image]

– depending on the quality of your images, you may want to run a blur/dilate/... or adjust the Empirical Stetson-Harrison value `0.9`.

Comment: further modified last line from print(text)  to print(int(text)) to prevent non-printable characters